# How to count rows with duplicate values in MYSQL, taking into account REGEXP or wildcards?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using this query, to count all rows in table "books", where the "name" column value repeats it self:

```
SELECT name, COUNT(*) c FROM books GROUP BY name HAVING c > 1
```

The thing is, that i would like to treat very similar book names, as "duplicates". For instance, books named "Good Book" and "Good Book." would be considered identical. I know, more or less, how to use REGEXP and wildcards, but i have no clue how to incorporate it to the query I'm using(if it's even possible..).

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Maybe you should consider a full text index instead of regexp.

Comment: I'm sorry...but what does it mean, "full text index"?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html

Comment: I see, but how would it be "incorporated" into the counting query I'm performing? Doesn't seem to solve the problem :-)

Comment: With a subquery maybe, considering that a record can be matched more than one time. There is no easy SQL solution, and maybe you should consider another way (like a custom algorithm). Otherwise, just filter the strings from their special characters. Maybe you should give more exemples in your question of what you want to match and what not

Comment: well, it would be sufficient for me, to actually match names that end with a "."(dot). For some stupid reason, my database has plenty of books with names, that end with an unnecessary dot. The operation I'm trying to achieve, doesn't allow me to just delete those rows.

Comment: DELETE FROM books WHERE RIGHT(name, 1) = '.' ? :)

Comment: DELETE..? I need to those records :->

Answer (score 1):

There is MYSQL string function called `SOUNDEX`. It's a long reach, but might just do what You need. `SOUNDEX` should return same "code-string" for two text strings that sound the same way. See [this link for more about SOUNDEX](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_soundex)

So you can try this for size

`SELECT SOUNDEX(name) as sname, COUNT(*) c FROM books GROUP BY sname HAVING c > 1`

Using regexp You would need to be more specific on the effect You want to achieve, as it's not clear from the ask whether You want to just remove the punctuation or there is more for you to see if things are similar.

Forward looking approach is to add another column, let's say `UNIFORM_NAME` and have a separate tool/process to populate that column, e.g. when adding items to table. This will be much useful if You plan to run such queries multiple times. You can then just use Your SQL code against this new column, and if You invent a new (better) way to harmonize the names for comparision, You can update that new column based on names and new algorithm, and rest of Your solution will work without need for further changes.

Comment: Well, thank you very much for the tips. I will just solve this issue using server side logic. I just thought that maybe SQL approach would be more "elegant".